# TSQL Performance - Should I Check For Data To Delete Or Just Delete?

Tags: performance, t-sql

I want to insert data for a single "session" from one table into another table. Before I do so I want to remove any pre-existing data concerning this same session by using a [Unique ID] column.

My question is:

Is it more efficient for me to check if the data exists & then delete it like so:

```
if (exists (select top 1 * from dbo.destinationTable where [Unique ID] = @unique_id))
begin;
    delete from dbo.destinationTable where [Unique ID] = @unique_id;
end;
```

Or is it better to simply run the delete statement without checking first:

```
delete from dbo.destinationTable where [Unique ID] = @unique_id;
```

Comment: delete doesn't fail if there is nothing to delete, so why check?

Comment: In this case having EXISTS, it nos necessary.

Comment: If you just use the `DELETE` you can check [`@@RowCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see if any rows were deleted. Or add an  [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause if you need to know which rows were deleted. Assuming you're using SQL Server. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to which is more efficient has to do more with data in your database, your database design, and the expected results than with the queries.  For instance if the table you are deleting from has no child tables and you would expect there to be records to delete almost all the time, then checking for existence is wasted effort. On the other hand, if you often will not have a record to delete or you would have the potential for lots of child records to delete in a cascade delete, it might make sense to check for existence first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My data doesn't require anything as complex as a cascade delete so I guess I will just stick with the delete statement for now.